# Creating lucene Index

Tags: lucene

My index is being created sucessfully.  My problem is that when trying the read it in Luke, I am getting an error:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: read past EOF
```

I am aware that Lucene does provide an option to not store a Field. However, what would be the best way to go about this?

- Store the field regardless of the size, and if a hit is found for a search, fetch the appropriate Field from Document OR
- Don't store the Field and if a hit is found for a search, query the data base to get the relevant information out?

Here is the code used to create the index:

```
public class CREATEiNDEX {
    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_43);
        Directory index = FSDirectory.open(new File("C:/toturials/luceneindex/"));
        IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_43, analyzer);
        IndexWriter w = new IndexWriter(index, config);
        List <String>list=readingPersonFile();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
            addDoc(w, String.valueOf(i),list.get(i));
        }
        w.close();
    }

    private static void addDoc(IndexWriter w, String title, String isbn) throws IOException {
        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.add(new StringField("Id", title, Field.Store.YES));
        doc.add(new TextField("Name", isbn, Field.Store.YES));
        w.addDocument(doc);
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide your search code. There could be some problem in way you are creating your query. I have written a simple tutorial for creating, adding and reading to Lucene, perhaps it can be of some assistance [http://weblog4j.com/2013/06/17/searching-made-easy-with-apache-lucene-4-3/](http://weblog4j.com/2013/06/17/searching-made-easy-with-apache-lucene-4-3/)

Comment: Maybe Luke is out Of Date or you did not commit your writes?

Comment: thanks for your comments i got the answer. problem with version and using analyzer.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should make new index after deleing the index.

Comment: i got the answer there is verson problem. as well as analyzer problem. i used whitespace analyzer.